# Strange Concurrency Behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently experiencing a strange behavior in this application I am building.

### Preface

This application I am building has a simple goal -- to take a collection of strings and search for each of those strings across multiple text files. The application also tracks unique matches for each string, i.e. string "abcd" will only be counted once if it appears n-times in file A.

Since this application will mainly be dealing with large numbers of files and large number of strings, I decided to do the string search in the background by creating a class that implements Runnable and using a ExecutorService to run the Runnable task. I also decided to investigate the speediness of the string search, so I started comparing the times using different methods of string matching (i.e. `String.contains()`, `String.indexOf()`, Boyer-Moore algorithm). I grabbed the source code of the Boyer-Moore algorithm from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/BoyerMoore.java.html and included it into my project. Here is where the problem started...

### The Problem

I noticed that the string search would come back with varying results (**each time I would run the search, the number of found strings would vary**) when using the `BoyerMoore` class so I replaced it with a `String.contains()` so that the code looks like the following...

```
private boolean findStringInFile(String pattern, File file) {
    boolean result = false;
    BoyerMoore bm = new BoyerMoore(pattern); // This line still causes varying results.
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        while(in.hasNextLine() && !result) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            result = line.contains(pattern);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Even with the above code, the results were still inconsistent. It seems like the instantiation of the `BoyerMoore` object is causing the results to vary. I dug a little deeper and found that the following code in the `BoyerMoore` constructor was causing this inconsistency...

```
// position of rightmost occurrence of c in the pattern
right = new int[R];
for (int c = 0; c < R; c++)
    right[c] = -1;
for (int j = 0; j < pat.length(); j++)
    right[pat.charAt(j)] = j;
```

Now I know **what** was causing the inconsistency but I still do not understand **why** it was happening. I'm no veteran when it comes to multi-threading so any possible explanation/insight is greatly appreciated!

### Below is the full code for the search task...

```
private class Search implements Runnable {
    private File mSearchableFile;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> mTable;

    public Search(File file,ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> table) {
        mSearchableFile = file;
        mTable = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Iterator<String> nodeItr = mTable.keySet().iterator();
        while(nodeItr.hasNext()) {
            String currentString = nodeItr.next();
            if(findStringInFile(currentString , mSearchableFile)) {
                Integer count = mTable.get(currentString) + 1;
                mTable.put(currentString,count);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean findStringInFile(String pattern, File file) {
        boolean result = false;
        // BoyerMoore bm = new BoyerMoore(pattern);
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
            while(in.hasNextLine() && !result) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                result = line.contains(pattern);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're searching files on disk, there's probably no point in parallelising the search. The disk speed will be the bottleneck if you're not buffering the files in memory up front.

Comment: Also, why would the code you cited cause an inconsistency? I can't see any shared data being manipulated in it. Or an explanation of what the "inconsistency" is. Did you actually check if, for the same pattern, you end up with different shift rule tables?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is yet.

Comment: @millimoose Inconsistency meaning, when I run the search (with the BoyerMoore object being instantiated BUT not used), the number of string hits is significantly different each time I run it.

Comment: "with the BoyerMoore object being instantiated but not used" - this means the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @millimoose But if I comment out the two for loops in the constructor of the BoyerMoore object, the results are returned in a consistent manner, as compared to when the lines were uncommented...

Comment: Simple rule of the thumb: if you use ConcurrentHashMap w/ put and get only it's likely you have some data race, or you are using the wrong Map.

Comment: Also re-reading (and closing) the file like that is suboptimal, you wish to check all patterns per line, not one pattern at a time. This is a serious performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should perform better as

- each file is only opened and closed once.
- no data is shared between threads so there is no inter-thread overhead (except the final result)

This gets the matches for each file and accumulates the count in a single thread.

```
static class Search implements Callable<Set<String>> {
    private final File file;
    private final Set<String> toFind;
    private final long lastModified;

    public Search(File file, Set<String> toSearchFor) {
        this.file = file;
        lastModified = file.lastModified();
        toFind = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>(toSearchFor);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> call() throws Exception {
        Set<String> found = new HashSet<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        while (in.hasNextLine() && !toFind.isEmpty()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            for (String s : toFind) {
                if (line.contains(s)) {
                    toFind.remove(s);
                    found.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();

        if (file.lastModified() != lastModified) 
            throw new AssertionError(file + " was modified");
        return found;
    }
}

public static Map<String, AtomicInteger> performSearches(
        ExecutorService service, File[] files, Set<String> toFind)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<Future<Set<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        futures.add(service.submit(new Search(file, toFind)));
    }
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> counts = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String s : toFind)
        counts.put(s, new AtomicInteger());
    for (Future<Set<String>> future : futures) {
        for (String s : future.get())
            counts.get(s).incrementAndGet();
    }
    return counts;
}
```

---

These lines are not thread safe.  Any number of threads can be updating the same key so the result will not be safe.

```
Integer count = mTable.get(currentString) + 1;
// another thread could be running here.
mTable.put(currentString,count);
```

A simple workaround is to use AtomicInteger (it will also simplify your code)

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> mTable;

for(Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry: mTable.entrySet()) 
    if(findStringInFile(entry.getKey(), mSearchableFile)) 
        entry.getValue().incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: Although this is very good advice, the behavior I am seeing still occurs even with AtomicInteger implemented.

Comment: Since the Map seems to be shared (i.e. passed in the c-tor), this should the correct answer... but who knows could be just a clone one :)

Comment: @AlexFu, do you wait for all the tasks to complete?

Comment: @AlexFu I assume the files and the strings are not changing in any way.  Not that it matter for your problem, openning and closing files is very expensive.  I would re-write it so each file is only openned once.  I would also re-write it so the Map is not shared line this.

Comment: @bestsss Yes. I have ruled this problem out because when I completely comment out the instantiation of the `BoyerMoore` object, the results come out as expected. Also I am using `ExecutorService.awaitTermination`

Comment: @AlexFu ...and you print the exceptions... and you have no pattern longer than 255 symbols? Your problematic line ends up w/ ArrayIndexOutBoundsException if the pattern is 256+ length (probably that should be a separate answer, hopefully Peter doesn't mind). Once an exception occurs the Execution is over for that thread.

Comment: `ecutorService.awaitTermination` means all the tasks finished, but it doesn't mean they finished without error.  See my example where I retained and check all the Future objects.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Your code is very insightful. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException when executing `future.get()`.

Comment: That should be fixed now.  Changed the collection.

Comment: Peter, using COW is kind of weird, just change to Iterator<String> i=toFind().iterator();... if(found) i.remove();... and LinkedHashSet (you can iterate in predictable way, although COW allows as well)

Comment: @bestsss I was being lazy ;) It is the simplest change which would fix the problem.